# In Android can I set the Handler(looper) priority?

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar, android-looper

I have this setup where a `Progressbar` show indetermient progress. Then I have this background Threads that surface on the main looper thread into a RecyclerView adapter.

The Threads simultaneously report progress to the `Progressbar` that have it´s own daemon thread listening, this in turn surfaces on the looper to show/set the `Progressbar` status.

My problem/question is that when the `Progressbar` daemon thread calls the looper to updates the `Progressbar`, the progress bar visualization is not smooth.

I wonder if when publishing to the Main Looper using a `Handler` if I could prioritets just like when creating  a normal Thread, so that `Progressbar` is smooth

Comment: when using "indeterminate" mode you dont have to "kick" `Progressbar` - it updates by itself

Comment: Yea but it stopps freezes when my ThreadPoolExecutor is working the Runnables. Would like a way to prioritets down the CPU use for the ThreadPoolExecutor, or prioritets a specific looper interaction

Comment: `Process#setThreadPriority` ?

Comment: Yea the `Progressbar` is indeterminate that´s all right - The worker Threads turn the `Progressbar` on and off, Thanks have to figure the "setThreadPriority " out, where/how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here´s an answer I guess, I experimenting with the ´Thread.setPriority()´ as  @pskink commented and it´s working I think. Here I set the `MIN_PRIORITY` and it´s slowing everything down almost to slow. A Priority of 3 is better. I think this should be set during runtime depending on the platform CPU

Class: BackgroundExecutorService.java

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;


import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    public enum BackgroundExecutorService {
        INSTANCE;

        /*
         * Max single thread ExecutorService that will spin down thread after use
         */
        private final Executor executor;

        {
            ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
                    5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(),
                    new ThreadFactory() {
                        @Override
                        public Thread newThread(@NonNull final Runnable r) {
                            Thread t = new Thread(r, "GooglePlaceExc" + "Thread");
                            t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
                            return t;
                        }
                    });
            executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
            this.executor = executor;
        }

        private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        public <R> void enqueue(final BackgroundJob<R> job) {
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        final R result = job.executeInBackground();
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                job.onSuccess(result);
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                job.onFailure(e);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```